# How do I set up a Java Environment Variable in a Spring Boot / Gradle / IntelliJ Environment?

Tags: java, heroku, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a configuration on my development environment to load DATABASE_URL that will also work on Heroku, with Heroku's DATABASE_URL. Unfortunately, non of the techniques I'm trying to create local environment variables seem to work in my Gradle/Boot/IntelliJ environment. Here is what I tried:

1. Adding a `export DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql...` to `/etc/environment`
2. Adding `-DDATABASEURL=jdbc:postgresql...` to my gradle task VM options (with bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties)
3. My make shift answer below, that I really don't like.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Spring can resolve environment variables automatically and, secondly, will resolve variables according to the order defined here (which is a Spring Boot doc page however the same should hold true for non Boot projects):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Setting the variables as an environemt vars in Heroku will then override the version in the properties file without any further coding required:

```
    //these properties will be resolved automatically from Heroku env vars if present
    //otherwise will be resolved from properties file bundled in the WAR
    @Value("${database.url}")
    String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${database.user}")
    String databaseUser;

    @Value("${database.password}")
    String databasePassword;

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {

        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(databaseUser);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);

        return basicDataSource;
    }
}
```

Add the vars from your local properties file that you wish to override to your app's Heroku settings by some means:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm answering my own question with the best answer I have, but really
>   hoping for a better one to accept!

I have a different properties file for each of my environments. In development.properties I added

```
localDatabaseUrl=postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/Nitro
```

And if I didn't find a DATABASE_URL environment variable, then I just read that one from the properties file:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${localDatabaseUrl}")
    String localDatabaseUrl;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {

        URI dbUri;
        try {
            dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
            log.info("Connecting via DATABASE_URL environment variable");
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            dbUri = new URI(localDatabaseUrl);
            log.info("Connecting via localDatabaseUrl properties key/value ***");
        }

        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(password);

        return basicDataSource;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you might prefer using `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` as described in [Heroku DevCenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url).

That said, either variable is fine. I also think fallback logic is fine too. But I would probably do it like this:

```
if (null == System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL")) {
  dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
} else {
  dbUri = new URI(localDatabaseUrl);
}
```

Another approach is to use a `.env` file and the `heroku local` command. Your `.env` file would contain:

```
JDBC_DATABASE_URL=postgres://...
```

The `heroku local` command will use the command in your `Procfile` to run your app. But this doesn't help when using `./gradlew bootRun` and other such tasks.

Comment: Thanks @codefinger. I know there is still a better way to create an environment variable that Java can read, on Ubuntu. Just waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pretty easily setup Heroku system variables that are "visible" by Spring using this command:

```
heroku config:set database.url=myDatabaseUrl -a myHerokuApp
```